# How put apps in a mysql database and display them

Tags: php, mysql, html, ajax, web-applications

I know this is easy to do. Though I want to know if there is a way upload apps to mysql database and a way to display them without the coding showing just the app. In php or html either or. I know a little in Ajax if there is a way in that.

If you even have a thought how I can start this. I would appreciate it.

Comment: Apps? as in an iphone or android app (a .apk file?). Before we can think about this for you, you should rephrase the question so it's less confusing.

Comment: Not really sure what you need help with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I expect there are a few reasons for storing an application in a database. Perhaps a user is permitted to design an app using JavaScript, and the code/template result is stored in a database row for future retrieval and rendering.

But, in the usual case, applications are stored on a filing system, and *interact* with the database. @gman has some good links to start reading up on.

Answer (score 0):

You don't really want to do this.

Simply store the apps name in the database which references a file, then include that file.

I might be missing something about your question, but you shouldn't store static code in your database.

Answer (score 0):

This question is really to vague to be answered properly here. What you should consider are some books on web development, with specific focus on PHP+MySQL, e.g.

- [Beginning PHP and MySQL](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004VJ2Z7M)
- [Learning PHP, MySQL, and JavaScript](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0043D2DZA)

To clarify, apps themselves are not "stored" in the database, but typically work in conjunction with a database backend to populate the data contained in the application. A coding language such as PHP is used to retrieve this data from the backend and display it using a markup language such as HTML.

Comment: +1 from me, but sadly someone else has downvoted (useful meme here - if you downvote, please say why).